# Why can't I assign a typescript generic type to a union of that type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeerror, typescript-generics

I have the following types in one of my webapps:

```
import React, {FC} from 'react';
import { Table, Tbody, Td, Th, Thead, Tr, chakra } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import { TriangleDownIcon, TriangleUpIcon } from '@chakra-ui/icons'
import {useTable, useSortBy, Column} from 'react-table'
import {Adult, Child} from "~/src/types/models";

type PersonTablePropData =
    | {
        persons: Adult[]
        columns: readonly Column<Adult>[]
      }
    | {
        persons: Child[]
        columns: readonly Column<Child>[]
      }

export type PersonTableProps = PersonTablePropData & {
    showPerson: (personId: number) => void
}

const PersonTable: FC<PersonTableProps> = ({ persons, showPerson, columns }) => {

  const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } =
    useTable<Adult|Child>({ columns, data: persons }, useSortBy)
...
```

This results in an error on ´columns´ in the last line:

```
Type 'readonly Column<Adult>[] | readonly Column<Child>[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly Column<Adult | Child>[]'.
```

This leaves me at a bit of a loss: Shouldn't `readonly Column<Adult>[]` be assiganble to `readonly Column<Adult | Child>[]`? As far as I can see, it would be a straight subset, so what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This leaves me at a bit of a loss: Shouldn't readonly Column[] be assiganble to readonly Column<Adult | Child>[]? As far as I can see, it would be a straight subset, so what is going wrong here?

You are absolutely right. It should be assignable under normal circumstances.

```js
type Adult = {
  tag: 'Adult',
  name: string,
  age: number
}

type Child = {
  tag: 'Child',
  school: number
}

let adult: Adult[] = []
let both: Array<Child | Adult> = []

both = adult // ok,
adult = both // error, as expected
```

However, this is not true with function arguments. Spoiler: contravariance.

```js
let adultFn = (arg: Adult[]) => { }
let bothFn = (arg: Array<Child | Adult>) => { }

bothFn = adultFn // error
adultFn = bothFn // ok
```

`adult` is no more assignable to `bothFn`. The arraw of inheritance change its way in an opposite direction.

Let's make it more closer to your example:

```js
type Adult = {
  tag: 'Adult',
  name: string,
  age: number
}

type Child = {
  tag: 'Child',
  school: number
}

type Options<T> = {
  columns: T[],
  handler: (arg: T) => void
}

let adult: Adult[] | Child[] = []

let hook = <T,>(arg: Options<T>) => { }

// same error as you have
hook<Adult | Child>({ columns: adult })
```

As you ,ight have noticed, this error is same as you have. Now, try to remove `handler: (arg: T) => void` from `Options<T>` type. Error will disapear. Why ? Because of contravariance. This is whats make your code more safer.
`useTable` hook uses under the hood `UseTableOptions` type, where provided generic `D` is used in a contravarian position - in a position of argument.

```js
type UseTableOptions<D extends object> = {
    columns: ReadonlyArray<Column<D>>;
    data: readonly D[];
} & Partial<{
    initialState: Partial<TableState<D>>;
    stateReducer: (newState: TableState<D>, action: ActionType, previousState: TableState<D>, instance?: TableInstance<D>) => TableState<D>;
    useControlledState: (state: TableState<D>, meta: Meta<D>) => TableState<D>;
    defaultColumn: Partial<Column<D>>;
    getSubRows: (originalRow: D, relativeIndex: number) => D[];
    getRowId: (originalRow: D, relativeIndex: number, parent?: Row<D>) => string;
    autoResetHiddenColumns: boolean;
}>
```

Please see another one simplified example:

```js
type Options<T> = {
  handler: (arg: T) => void
}

type SuperType = string;
type SubType = 'hello'

declare let superType: SuperType;
declare let subType: SubType;

superType = subType // ok
subType = superType // error


let superTypeObj: Options<SuperType> = {
  handler: (arg) => { }
}


let subTypeObj: Options<SubType> = {
  handler: (arg) => { }
}

// opposite direction
superTypeObj = subTypeObj // error
subTypeObj = superTypeObj // ok
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WY4vbm)

More about *-variance you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66410115/difference-between-variance-covaraince-contravariance-and-bivariance-in-typesc) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RH49aarW6sU)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are trying to assign type **Adult[]** which is an array, to the type **Adult** which is not an Array Type.